# while loop checking for two booleans always runs

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm a beginner at java and I just recently started to study interfaces so I triead to make a program that had classes which implemented intefaces. Anyways, i ran into a problem with the while loop in my program. I'm tryng to give the user the opportunity to choose between talking to a robor or a person, and as far as i understand `&&` checks for both of the conditions (If either one of them is true it runs the loop).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ai = new Scanner(System.in);
    Conversation guy = new Human();
    Conversation rox = new Robot();
    System.out.println("What do you want to talk to?");
    String choice = ai.nextLine();
    while (choice != "Robot" && choice!= "Person"){
        System.out.println("Option not available, choose again.");
        choice = ai.nextLine();
    }
    switch(choice){
    case "Person":
        System.out.println("What's my name?");
        guy.greet();
        guy.conv();
        guy.bye();
        break;
    case "Robot":
        System.out.println("What's my name?");
        rox.greet();
        rox.conv();
        rox.bye();
        break;
    }
    ai.close();

    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that if the input is neither `"Person"` or `"Robot"` it scans again for new input but despite the input being either one the program always runs the loop, Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing Objects (`String`) using `==` which compares references here:

```
choice != "Robot" && choice!= "Person"
```

You need to use the `.equals()` method to compare Strings meaningfully

Comment: thanks that solved. I'm still trying to get myhead around the difference between using `==` and `.equals()` but it worked  so thanks.

Comment: @DiegoPerozo `==` compares Object references, to see if they are pointing to the same actual object in memory. `.equals()` is a method in the `Object` class which is therefore inherited by all classes. You can implement it however you want. For the `String` class, the developers have implemented a meaningful `.equals()` which compares all the characters in the String to the target String and returns true only if they match.

Comment: That's the drawback of not having String as a primitive type.